# Config routing asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

if i have routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                //url: "{action}",
                url: "{controller}/{contynent}/{country}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", kontynent=UrlParameter.Optional , panstwo= UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

now in my page i can use:

```
localhost:4084/Home
localhost:4084/World
localhost:4084/World/Europe
localhost:4084/World/Europe/England
```

but in this case i can use only action equals `Index` and @Html.ActionLink don't give any results :( (moves me to: `http://localhost:4084/?action=Action&controller=Controller`).
How change MapRoute to form, where i can use:

```
localhost:4084/Home/About (controller=Home, action=About)
localhost:4084/Home/SignIn (controller=Home, action=SignIn)
localhost:4084/World/Europe (controller=World, action=Index, contynent=Europe)
localhost:4084/World/Europe/England (controller=World, action=Index, contynent=Europe, country=England)
```

Best way i want to create exception for World controller in MapRoute.

Comment: Can you please show what code you want to get working? "@Html.ActionLink don't give any results" is not very descriptive...

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("test", "Action", "Controller") moves me to:
localhost:4084/?action=Action&controller=Controller

Comment: Please do not update your question using comments.  Edit the question itself so future users do not have to read all the comments to fully understand the question.

Comment: You should be leaving the default route as it was and adding a custom one above it. MVC routes are tested in order of appearance - you leave the default route that is there at the end as the fallback for errors.